# Flask-SQLAlchemy pagination with keywords returns an empty list

Tags: python, filter, sqlalchemy, pagination

I have an issue with flask paginate. Upon advice here at Stackoverflow I solved an initial paginate typeerror by changed my code so the paginate takes keywords. This gave me a new issue, since my code now returns an empty list of tickers.

The issue seems to be related to the implementation of paginate with keywords and the filter_by function, since my code returns a list of stocks from all exchanges when i remove the filter for CPH. So below code is working, but gives my tickers for all exchanges and obviously not only the ones with exchange='CPH':

```
@app.route("/stocks/cphstocks")
@login_required
def cphstocks():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    **tickers = Ticker.query.paginate(page=page, per_page=app.config['TICKERS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)**
    next_url = url_for('cphstocks', page=tickers.next_num) \
        if tickers.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('cphstocks', page=tickers.prev_num) \
        if tickers.has_prev else None

    return render_template('cphstocks.html', title='Copenhagen Stocks', tickers=tickers.items, next_url=next_url,
                           prev_url=prev_url)
```

My code with keywords in paginate and the filtering is shown below. Does anyone know what I'm missing here, since it's not returning the tickers for exchange='CPH'? Advice is much appreciated!

```
@app.route("/stocks/cphstocks")
@login_required
def cphstocks():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    tickers = Ticker.query.filter_by(index="CPH").paginate(
        page=page, per_page=app.config['TICKERS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
    next_url = url_for('cphstocks', page=tickers.next_num) \
        if tickers.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('cphstocks', page=tickers.prev_num) \
        if tickers.has_prev else None

    return render_template('cphstocks.html', title='Copenhagen Stocks', tickers=tickers.items, next_url=next_url,
                           prev_url=prev_url)
```

And my jinja template:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <article class="media content-section">
          <div class="media-body">
              <h3>Copenhagen listed stocks</h3>
              </br>
              <p></p>
          </div>
    </article>
     <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm w-auto small">
          <caption>Stocks listed at Copenhagen stock exchange</caption>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-left"scope="col">Ticker</th>
              <th class="text-right"scope="col">Company</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for items in tickers %}
            <tr>
              <td scope="row"> <a href="{{ url_for('stockpage', id=items.id) }}">{{ items.yahoo_ticker }}</td>
              <td class="text-right">{{ items.company_name }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>    {% if prev_url %}
        <a href="{{ prev_url }}">Previous page</a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if next_url %}
        <a href="{{ next_url }}">Next page</a>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="content-section">
            <h3>New menu </h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><a href="https://finance.yahoo.com" target="_blank">Visit Yahoo Finance</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light"><a href="{{ url_for('stocks_update1') }}">Update1</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</a></li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</a></li>
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using filter instead of filter_by, so code that works is as below:

```
   tickers = Ticker.query.filter(Ticker.exchange.contains('CPH')).paginate(page=page, per_page=app.config['TICKERS_PER_PAGE'], error_out=False)
```